# How to make scrollable JPanel displaying JLabels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, jscrollpane

I have a list of `JLabels` which are 280 x 50 and contain text. I want to create 280 x 300 `JPanel`, add all the labels to it and make it scrollable (since we can have more than 6 labels).

I am not sure how to add more than 6 labels to the panel of this particular size nor how to make it scrollable (I tried to add the panel to `JScrollPane` of the same size but nothing really happened). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: First, stop screwing with the size of the containers. The container's size needs to be dynamically calculated based on the it's content, only then will a `JScrollPane` be able to work

Comment: I do have to wonder if a JList held within a JScrollPane is what you *really* need. The JList can act like a grid of JLabels, just more efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, stop trying screwing with the size of the components.  Swing already has a very powerful layout manager API which takes into consideration many different aspects of GUI frameworks and platform and hardware differences, let it do it's job.

A `JScrollPane` is depended on it's content been able to calculate it's size independently of the size of the `JScrollPane`, only then can it decide when it should show scroll bars.  This also goes for the `JPanel`.  It's size should be calculated based on the total requirements of it's contents.  Oddly enough, all this is done for free if you make use of the layout manager API.

So, a quick a nasty example might look something like...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(new TestPane()));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            for (int index = 0; index < 600; index++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("This is test " + index);
                // This is for demonstration purposes only
                // you should let the lable calculate its size based on its text
                // and image properties
                label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 50));
                add(label, gbc);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

> But the window is to long!

So, this becomes slightly more complicated.  You need to be able provide additional hints to the `JScrollPane` about how you'd like the component to be size.  For this, there is `Scrollable`...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(new TestPane()));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            for (int index = 0; index < 600; index++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("This is test " + index);
                // This is for demonstration purposes only
                // you should let the lable calculate its size based on its text
                // and image properties
                label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 50));
                add(label, gbc);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(290, 300);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 128;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 128;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

## But...

This all raises the question of, Why?  Why not just use a `JList` or `JTable` which already pretty much does all this?

Comment: I need JLabels because I need 280x50 rectangles, which can change background upon entering (for purpose of my program design). They contain an image and text. I am not sure `JList` or `JTable` would allow me to stay with my design.

Comment: There’s probably ways to do it, but I’m not awake enough yet to think about it 